# Understanding StreamGobbler

Tags: java, runtime.exec, outputstream

I am implementing a `mailx` command through Runtime.exec and came across this article which explains the right way of doing it.

[JavaWorld : Runtime.exec](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4)

I have been through the examples and see that they have introduced a new class `StreamGobbler` which accepts the InputStream and prints the output.
However I fail to understand the reason why this has been introduced. Can anybody please explain.

Also as part of my code , I have written the following

```
OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream())
osw.write(mailBody)
osw.close
```

Is this implementation correct or there are any pitfalls to it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handle Input using StreamGobbler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258243/handle-input-using-streamgobbler)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your program can potentially succeed (which means the program's output would be available on the `Process'` `getInputStream()`) or it can potentially fail (which means the program's error would be available on the `Process'` `getErrorStream()`, you should be able to read these in parallel and hence the need for a separate thread which is implemented by the `StreamGobbler` class. Hope this clarifies to an extent.

Answer (score 0):

Say you don't use the StreamGobbler solution and simply use `getInputStream()` to obtain the standard output produced by the program. If the execution of the program generates only standard error output, your Java code may hang when you try to read the `InputStream` returned by `getInputStream()`. I say "may hang" because I believe the behavior may vary depending on your execution environment. I ran into this issue when executing a JUnit test.

Answer (score 0):

ProcessBuilder has a method to redirect the error stream to the input stream ([ProcessBuilder.redirectErrorStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream%28%29)) so you do not need a separate thread to read the streams in parallel.  However, InputStream.read may block and is [not interruptable](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4514257) via Thread.interrupt, so if you need to put a timeout on the read you may want to use a separate thread "StreamGobbler".